# Hosting-specific code in projects: push to Github too?

Tags: git, deployment, workflow, hosting, github

Imagine this common scenario: i hacked together a cool project i want to share with the world. So: i put it on Github, and fetch it from Github on my own website so people can see a demo. This also makes updating easy: just push from my local box to Github, fetch on my server.

I'd like to track visitors so i add Google Analytics and maybe some other site-specific stuff (like a global header for all pages on my site) to the project. However, everybody who checks out my project from Github gets all that stuff too.

There are a few solutions to prevent that. I could make a specific 'deployment branch' for my website, but that's cumbersome. I could make some kind of switch in my code (`if ip === myip showStats()`), but that's ugly.

Another option might be to use githooks, but i haven't got any experience with that.

Any other suggestions? Are people even bothered when getting deployment-specific code like that in their checkouts?

Comment: I suspect it is not a Java web application in which case you can practically configure everything outside the web application or web application directory?

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Breun's suggestion, (so your question will be double answered) I deploy my Python projects with a settings.py file which defines the settings that are needed on the production machine. (debug=False, proper database settings and file paths...)

At the end of the file, I try to import developmentsettings.py like this:

```
try:
    from projectnaam import developmentsettings
except:
    pass
```

The file does not exist in version control, so this will fail and silently pass on the server. On my dev machine, I manually create the file and override specific settings to match my dev needs. (things like sqlite instead of postgres)

This can be extended into a more sophisticated deployment strategy, involving stuff like Fabric, Buildout, Capistrano and Chef. This all gets more important when working in (distributed) teams.

*My current development flow now goes like: edit code, $ git commit -m "comment", $ git push, $ fab deploy master production (<- this pulls 'master' from origin onto the server)*

Answer (score 1):

Create a configuration file for deployment-specific settings. You could for instance have a conf/defaults.conf for any default settings and let users put any local deployment-specific overrides in conf/local.conf.

Answer (score 0):

And add your settings.php file to the .gitignore, otherwise you might upload it.

Sharing your Google analytics (api)code with the world isn't a good idea because your stats are going to be screwed up of someone uses your code without changing it.